# Unable to load dependent .proto files with gRPCUI

Tags: c#, asp.net, grpc, grpcurl

I have a simple gRPC app. I have 2 proto files.

**1. greet.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "protos/common.proto";
option csharp_namespace = "Module.SubModule.API";
package greet;

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
  Error error = 2;
}
```

**2. common.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "Module.SubModule.API";
package greet;

message Error {
    int32 status_code = 1;
}
```

**File Structure**

[image: Project File Structure]

**Project File Entry**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\common.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I run the app and then use `grpcui localhost:5001`, I get the below error message

```
Failed to compute set of methods to expose: Symbol not found: greet.Greeter
caused by: File not found: protos/common.proto
```

Can anyone help out here? The common.proto file is in the same directory and the app runs fine without any build errors. But when using gRPCUI, I get this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a server reflection issue. Looking at the readme on github - [Proto Source Files](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcui#proto-source-files) it says about including an import path for dependecies to be included correctly, if server relection isn't supported.

This article might help too [gRPC Server Reflection in the .NET world](https://martinbjorkstrom.com/posts/2020-07-08-grpc-reflection-in-net)

Comment: Yeah, looks like a reflection issue. I have read the above links already. The problem is the docs are very minimal and not much is available on the web too. I tried a lot of combinations but did not get them to work.

Comment: I know this is going to sound obvious, but have you tried matching the case on the "Protos" folder in the import declaration?  Somethings can be quite picky about that.

Comment: Also, what happens if you put Error straight into the Greeter file without the import.  Does it work then?

Comment: Yes, I tried to match that. Same issue. Yes, if they are in the same file it works. The issue is with the common file not being imported somehow.

Comment: Ok last through of the dice -> https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/csharp/server_reflection.md

Comment: I went through this too :) Searched for a way to customize the reflection service, but to no avail. Thanks for the efforts though!